# Using JQuery in asp.net view to display commas in currency value SPAN area

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am a newbie with JQuery. I am have number like 25000.00 but I need it to look like 25,000.00 and not let any validation error in the Model State.
I tried using @string.Format("{0:C}", Model.CurrentFaceAmount) but validation error will catch it.

I found an article with JQuery. Add the script like so in the VIEW

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.fn.digits = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,"));
        });
    }
</script>
```

and I added like so in the value area

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">$("span.number").digits();</span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CurrentFaceAmount, new {@class = "form-control", @type = "number", data_inputmask = @Html.InputMaskFor(x => x.CurrentFaceAmount) })

</div>
```

In the article, it says the following

```
$.fn.digits = function(){ 
    return this.each(function(){ 
        $(this).text( $(this).text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") ); 
    })
}
```

You could then use it like this:

```
$("span.numbers").digits();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

$("span.number") looks for `<span class="number"></span>` and it won't work in the middle of the html code. what you need to do is to add `<script>` in the end of your document:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("input#CurrentFaceAmount").digits();
});
</script>
```

the first script line tells the script to run after the document is loaded so the html elements could be found. when the document is ready, it runs the function that finds an input element with the id "CurrentFaceAmount".